# AttributeError in Theano

Tags: python, theano

I am trying to run the installation test of the Theano with the following code:

```
 import theano
 theano.test()
```

However, I would see the following error corresponding to blas.py:

```
/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/blas.py in default_blas_ldflags()
    301     try:
    302         #if numpy was linked with library that are not installed, we can't reuse them.
--> 303         if all(not os.path.exists(dir) for dir in numpy.distutils.__config__.blas_opt_info['library_dirs']):
    304             return "-lblas"
    305         return ' '.join(

   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__config__'
```

I understand that AttributeError is a famous error and there are questions asked about it, but for Theano the only solution I found on the internet was to add:

```
import numpy.distutils.config
```

to the blas.py. However, this does not solve the problem and I am still facing the AttributeError.

Comment: is your numpy installed through anaconda?

Comment: @JamesTobin No. It is through Enthought Canopy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in Theano development version.

Use one of those 2 command to update Theano depending if the installation is just for your user or for the OS:

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git --user
pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
```

Here is the doc for that update:

```
http://www.deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#bleeding-edge-install-instructions
```